# Mocha Grep Regex for specific test

Tags: regex, mocha.js

I have the following project https://github.com/invertednz/mocha-example

It has 4 tests:

```
starts should return -1 when the value is not present
should return -1 when the value is not present
should return -1 when the value is not present2
should return -1 when the value is not present 3
```

I want to use --grep so that I only run "should return -1 when the value is not present"

I wanted to use "^should return -1 when the value is not present$" but I believe the describe section messes this up.

The above represents a somewhat contrived example, I am being returned a testname that I need to run from an api and then I just want to run that specific test, I am unsure of all the test names that maybe present.

For example I would in this case know that I want to run 'should return -1 when the value is not present' but not know that 'starts should return -1 when the value is not present' exists.

I was wondering if I could use the describe like:

```
Array #indexOf().should return -1 when the value is not present$
```

What regex should I use?

Answer (score 1):

For this specific set of strings you could use something as simple as:

```
^(?!starts).*present$
```

Which would simply ensure that the first string is not matched by using a negative lookahead while the 3rd and 4th strings are not matched due to the match ending immediately after `present`.

Comment: Hey Chris,  sorry I'm looking for a more generic answer which will work with other situations.  Thanks though so much for the answer!  I'm returning a test which I want to run and I just want to make sure that is the only test I run this was just a contrived example.

Comment: Sure thing, myself (or another user reading this question) may be able to help with a more generic approach. Can you add any examples of other types of situations you would encounter to the OP? I may be able to modify the regex to handle multiple cases. I only gave a specific answer because the title of the question said "specific test."

Comment: Hey Chris, I really appreciate your help: this best describes the situation:
I am being returned a testname that I need to run from an api and then I just want to run that specific test, I am unsure of all the test names that maybe present.  I have the describe section as well so I also tried ="Array #indexOf() should return -1 when the value is not present$"